# php encode json array just first column

Tags: php, json, jquery-autocomplete

I need to enconde just the first column of an array with n rows,

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [FamilyName] => Dikkartan, Bartu
        [Balance] => -2446.91
        [Mobile] => 0444497
        [HAddress] => 2/6 Tramsway Street
        [HSuburb] => Rosebery
        [HState] => NSW
        [HPCode] => 

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [FamilyName] => King, Alan & Luka
        [Balance] => -1676
        [Mobile] => 0433 6090
        [HAddress] => 46/12 Hayberry Street
        [HSuburb] => Crows Nest
        [HState] => NSW
        [HPCode] => 

    ) ...
```

so I need to make an array just with the first value [familyName],
- I want to have this to use with a jquery autocomplete, so after having the name selected from autocomplete, I use this name to search again in the complete array and fill some textfields with the data from the array

- I need to search in the array as data is taken from sql, but I cannot search in the db, just use the array data,
- Is this a good path or what other path should I take to do some autocomplete for the name and then have my textfields filled with the data from that array

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) you can reduce the array to just that element.

```
$familyNames = array_map(function($object) {
    return $object['FamilyName'];
}, $objects);

json_encode($familyNames);
```

This uses an anonymous function available in php 5.3 otherwise you need to use create_function or a reference to an existing function you've created. See the PHP [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) documentation.

```
create_function('$object', 'return $object["FamilyName"];')
```

Alternatively you could use a simple foreach loop:

```
$familyNames = array();
foreach($objects as $object)
    $familyNames[] = $object['FamilyName'];
```

Comment: Or just a normal function if you're not too proud to write one.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Haha, I always forget about that, I'm too used to simple anonymous functions for this :D I'll add it in for completeness.

Comment: thanks a lot!!, I ended up using the foreach loop, as I have php 5.2.6